# Gembox document removes table of contents

Tags: c#, gembox-document

I'm using Gembox document to replace some text in a docx document and it works great. However, I have a table of contents field that disappears after saving the document.
I tried doing the following but the field still disappears leaving only the placeholder text:

```
var toc = (TableOfEntries)document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.TableOfEntries).First();
toc.Update();
document.GetPaginator(new PaginatorOptions() { UpdateFields = true });
```

Comment: Can you share your DOCX file so that I can reproduce this issue and investigate it?

Comment: This is the test file I'm using https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVG4Ymm8BlSz99WAQi263TN_rJ7rWnA5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (2021-01-15):**

Please try again with the latest version from the [BugFixes](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/downloads/bugfixes.html) page or from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Document/).

The latest version will work on the machine that uses culture with ';' character as a list separator.
Or you can specify that culture like this:

```
var toc = (TableOfEntries)document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.TableOfEntries).First();

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
toc.Update();

document.GetPaginator(new PaginatorOptions() { UpdateFields = true });
```

Also, the issue with the missing tab stop should be resolved now as well.

**ORIGINAL:**

When I tried to update your TOC from MS Word, I got the following:

> No table of contents entries found.

After investigating the field's code of your TOC element, I figured out what the problem is.
This is the instruction text that you have:

```
{ TOC \h \z \t "TitreChapitre;1;SousTitreChapitre;2" }
```

These semicolon character separators (<kbd>;</kbd>) are culture-dependent. In other words, updating this TOC element will work on a machine that has a French region and settings, but it won't work when you have an English region and settings.

I'm currently on vacation, so I can't do anything about this. When I come back I will fix this problem for you.

For now, can you use the following as a workaround (I also noticed an issue with missing `TabStop`, this workaround will cover that as well):

```
var toc = (TableOfEntries)document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.TableOfEntries).First();            
var section = toc.Parent as Section;

var tocWidth = section.PageSetup.PageWidth - section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Left - section.PageSetup.PageMargins.Right;

var toc1Style = document.Styles["toc 1"] as ParagraphStyle;
var toc1TabStop = new TabStop(tocWidth - toc1Style.ParagraphFormat.RightIndentation, TabStopAlignment.Right, TabStopLeader.Dot);
toc1Style.ParagraphFormat.Tabs.Add(toc1TabStop);

var toc2Style = document.Styles["toc 2"] as ParagraphStyle;
var toc2TabStop = new TabStop(tocWidth - toc2Style.ParagraphFormat.RightIndentation, TabStopAlignment.Right, TabStopLeader.Dot);
toc2Style.ParagraphFormat.Tabs.Add(toc2TabStop);

toc.InstructionText = toc.InstructionText.Replace(';', ',');
toc.Update();

document.GetPaginator(new PaginatorOptions() { UpdateFields = true });
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great. The only drawback though, is that the table of contents field is not updatable manually anymore so we can't update it if we change any header text.

Comment: @yqit Please check the updated answer. Let me know if you need anything else.